# is there an URL filter API in chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, opera-extension

Old Opera 12 had an easy option to build own ad-blocking extension: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/extensions-api-urlfilter/

My question is: Is there a similar thing in google chrome extension format ? (also this should apply for new opera series)

(This is a question also about how various adblocks for chrome are made. I mean do these extensions actually block traffic before the browser sends request ? Is this capacity available in chrome extensions ?)

Comment: It's unclear what *programming-related question* you are asking here.

Comment: This question is about capability of chrome extension api. Can it block content before it gets fetched from the server.

Comment: I highly doubt it.  How can it block what it doesn't see? (unless it has an URL blacklist in it, or something like that)

Comment: Yes, but I ask if someone know which api to invoke to use such functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two APIs that can be used for blocking web content:

1. The [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) API.
2. The [`chrome.declarativeWebRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest.html) API.

The declarativeWebRequest is currently only available on the dev channel, but I expect that it will become available on the stable channel within a few releases. Although it's possible to block requests using the webRequest API, I recommend to use the declarative one, because it's more efficient, in two ways: it allows you to use [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html) instead of [background pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html), and the filters are fully implemented in native code.

The format of the URL filters of the declarativeWebRequest API are very expressive, its format can be found at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events.html#type-UrlFilter.

The format of the URL filter in the declarativeWebRequest API follows the format of a [match pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html) (similar to Opera's url filter).

I've posted a simple example of both APIs at [Block URL with a specific word somewhere in the subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956976/block-url-with-a-specific-word-somewhere-in-the-subdomain). Don't forget to [declare the right permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html) in the manifest file. Either `"declarativeWebRequest"` or `"webRequest", "webRequestBlocking"`. To block an URL using the webRequest API, you must also request permissions to access the URLs you want to block in the manifest file.