# How to write the js for a chrome extension that blocks a specific site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've spent a good few hours trying to crack this myself, having analysed a bunch of other people's work (this is the latest one I've tried to hack [Block URL with a specific word somewhere in the subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956976/block-url-with-a-specific-word-somewhere-in-the-subdomain) ), and have come up none the wiser.

I feel like the js shouldn't really be that complex, I'm just trying to block a webpage and surface an error message in its place.

This is where I've netted out atm:

```
chrome.declarativeWebRequest.onRequest.addRules({
  id: 'some rule id',
  conditions: [
    new chrome.declarativeWebRequest.RequestMatcher({
      url: {
        host: 'www.dailymail.com'
      }
    })
  ],

  actions: [
    new chrome.declarativeWebRequest.CancelRequest()
  ]
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you make the script recognise the word in the domain? Please post code.

Comment: I mean in your post, so others can see it with formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The answer at [Block URL with a specific word somewhere in the subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956976/block-url-with-a-specific-word-somewhere-in-the-subdomain) works as expected. When it does not work, follow the following steps to troubleshoot the problem:

1. **[Open the background page's console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension/10258029#10258029) and look for error messages**.
   Search for the error message on Google, and try to understand the recommended results. Trustworthy sources include [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension), the [extension documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/index), [Chromium's bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list), the [chromium-extensions](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/forum/chromium-extensions) and [chromium-apps](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/forum/chromium-apps) mailing lists.
2. Check whether you have added the correct permissions to your [manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest).
3. If you have just added the new permissions, make sure that you have reloaded the extension (e.g. by clicking on Reload at `chrome://extensions/`).

With the information you've provided, I can think of three reasons for failure:

1. Are you using [Chromium beta](https://www.google.com/landing/chrome/beta/), [Chromium dev](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) (or even Canary)? If not, then either install Chrome from one of these channels, or use the webRequest API instead. The `declarativeWebRequest` API is currently *not* available on the stable channel, only on the beta and developer channels.
2. `url` is an object of the type [`UrlFilter`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#type-UrlFilter). There is no property called "host", if you want to match an exact host, use `hostEquals`, like this:

   ```
   url: {
       hostEquals: 'www.dailymail.com'
   }
   ```
3. You have not added the correct permissions. To get your demo to work, you need to declare the `declarativeWebRequest` and `*://www.dailymail.com/*` permissions in the manifest file.